# Kubuntu 18.04 volume control stops working randomly and cannot switch to headphones

Tags: sound, kubuntu, pulseaudio, alsa

Basically what the title says. Volume control stops working randomly. There is sound, but volume control can only mute or turn sound on at one constant level. Regardless if it's at 5% or 100%, the volume doesn't change. When it happens Kubuntu doesn't switch to headphones either.

Using FN keys, kubuntu volume control or alsamixer makes no difference. volume can only be on or off.

I wasn't able to discern any pattern for when it stops. The issue is usually fixed after restarting, but not always. I tried restarting alsa, but it makes not difference.

Some info about my system:

```
cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Realtek ALC255
Codec: Intel Broxton HDMI

uname -srv
Linux 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018
```

After some reading I added the last 3 lines in my alsa-base.conf, but it doesn't seem to make any difference either.

```
options snd-pcsp index=-2
alias snd-card-0 snd-hda-intel
alias sound-slot-0 snd-hda-intel
options snd-hda-intel model=auto
```

Day 02 Update:

After about 20 reboots and shutdowns I found out that my volume control is broken 100% of the time when I reboot into Ubuntu from Windows 10. After shutting down Windows or rebooting into Ubuntu from Ubuntu there is no issue. Is a Windows driver breaking my sound card? Whoa!

Day 07 Update:

After a couple of days of testing I can now dismiss this as a Windows Driver messing up my hardware.

Update:

I stand corrected. It did happen after rebooting Ubuntu into Ubuntu. Updating pulsaudio the other day didn't resolve the issue permanently either.

Comment: Install Pulseaudio Volume Control (pavucontrol). This will show a lot more than panel volume control. If problem is just in your current volume control, pavucontrol would still work. if both fail it would suggest a deeper problem with Pulseaudio. pavucontrol may not fix all your audio problems, but you will be able to see more of what is happening to ask more detailed questions

Comment: I had pavucontrol-qt by default. I removed it alongside alsa -base and pulseaudio, rebooted and then reinstalled alsa-base and pulseaudio. I tried kmix. Issue still appears after a couple of hours.
I doubt it's an issue with the control software since all control applications I tried cannot change the volume and only turn it on/off once the issue appears.

Comment: So 2 weeks later it seems the issues is not coming from Windows. It happens after cold boot as well, regardless if the previous session was in Windows or Ubuntu.
I also tried pulseaudio --kill && alsa force-reload when the issue is present. The services are restarted, but it doesn't help. 
Having pavucontrol or kmix and reinstalling alsa and pulseaudio or updating, doesn't change anything as well.